# Expiration of patent 5,580,417 as well as technology used in tensioning cap in Figure 5

Tags: patentability, expired-patent

My first question has to do with patent #5,580,417.  I believe this patent is expired, but are there any other patents in force using the same technology?

My second question is in regards to the tensioning cap in Figure 5.  Is this technology or concept expired?  Is it in force in another patent?  Or is it too broad to be patented.

Thank you.

Comment: You also find following previous answers [How do you determine a patent's expiration date?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/q/3801/11895) ;; 
[How can I perform a global patent search for free?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/q/21/11895)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you determine a patent expiration date?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/3801/how-do-you-determine-a-patent-expiration-date)