# How to find information for a Organization

Tags: search, formula

I have made a replication of this foundation. I have also switched out 1 major ingredient and added another. How can I find their patent information to examine more of this formula?

Comment: Duplicate of [How can I perform a global patent search for free?](http://patents.stackexchange.com/q/21/11895)

Comment: For more information on applicant searching http://patents.stackexchange.com/q/11951/11895

Comment: @Robert Cartaino. Too Vague

Comment: thank you for comment but for generalized question we follow the link for search database. In search database help file you will get information how and where to look. We also provided you link on how to search applicant(organization). I feel our moderator has given sufficient information based on information listed in question.